# DynamoDB - Indirect many-to-many relation

Tags: database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, database-schema

I'm new to DynamoDB and I'm trying to create a DynamoDB design to represent the relation below:

[image: many-to-many-relation]

The query I'd like to serve is whether a user has a content. As you can see, a user may have a content either directly or through a content collection. I can probably create a single table and do something like this:

[image: dynamo-schema]

However, the problem is that when I'd like to know whether user 1 has content 3, I need to make two queries. Is there a better strategy to handle this in a single query?

Some notes:

- ContentCollection is mutable, so duplication could be an issue.
- ContentCollection may contain thousands of Contents, so it isn't an option to normalize it as data would grow exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

in order to prevent multiple queries you would need to put Content#3 under the User#1 PK as well, maybe like `SK: CONTENTCOLLECTION#2' attribute # CONTENT#3"

of course this gets very unweildy very fast. Many to Many is a relationship that is not very easiy to replicate in Dynamo. It may also result in more Writes, but this is generally OK because Writes are generally cheaper/quicker than reads in most situations (rule of thumb: 2 writes is ok, 2 reads is not - which you seem to get already)

Fact of the matter is, you have your data designed in a storage first solution - that is you figured it be better to have one object type of user, one of Content, and one of Content Collections. This is all fine and dandy for general situations - and would be perfectly fine for an SQL db, but the moment you try and force a single access pattern onto it it falls apart.

This is doubly re-enforced by the start of your question: You want to create a dynamo pattern to fit this data relationship pattern.  You should instead be asking: I will have this piece of information and I want to be able to get these things - How do I design my dynamo schema to facilitate this?

You might want to reconsider your access patterns and design your dynamo schema based on that. It is a much harder way to think about things - especially if you have a history of designing SQL databases that *are* done best Storage First rather than Access First.

There isnt really enough information here for me to really give a good answer to a better access pattern, but you might consider why you have Content and ContentCollection.

If you want to be able to store data by some sort of tag you could use a Sparse Index - ie, Content#1 has an attribute of ContentCollection#1: True and ContentCollection#2 True - but Content#2 doesn't even have the attribute ContentCollection#1 because its not part of it. A Sparse Index formed off ContentCollection#1 would give you all that were in it. Of course, this can become very unwieldy if you have more than a few content collections as well. But maybe it will inspire you.

Any way you slice it though, trying to do this Many to Many relationship results in either an exponentially growing complexity of additional attributes on every User/ContentCollection or two queries.